# Wrong rep in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, reputation

[image: Screenshot of the Jewish Life and Learning chat room, showing a message from Double AA, with the number "10.2k" under his name.]

Only problem is, last I checked I only have 9322 reputation (and counting!)

Why does it say I have 10.2k?

Comment: +1, [baruch shekivanti](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5350857#5350857).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your chat account is tied to your network-wide account, not to your Judaism.SE account. The score associated with it is your aggregate rep across all SE sites, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sort of. Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange are excluded, as they have their own chat systems, but all other SE sites share a chat system. It's a bit weird, really.