# Chat badges on meta.J.SE

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, badges, meta

Is it possible to get the chat badges ([talkative](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/65/talkative) and [outspoken](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/67/outspoken)) on meta.J.SE? If chat is [site independent](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/882/759), how are the badges different for each site? Can meta.J.SE have its own chat rooms or are they by default categorized under the parent site?

---

**Edited to update:**

As described in [the answer below](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/907), it is seemingly *not* possible to get the chat badges on meta. Their existence, then, is a bug. I'm retagging this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) therefore (and dropping [support](/questions/tagged/support)).

---

Edit: I realized the issue also exists with regards to the bounty badges ([Promoter](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/46/promoter) and [Benefactor](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/47/benefactor) as well as [Investor](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/45/investor) and [Altruist](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/48/altruist)) as there are no bounties here on meta.

Comment: I wonder whether extended comments on this site that the site suggests get taken to chat will yield a room that allows for such badges. Respond to me here, Double AA: let's try it out. `:-)`

Comment: @msh210 What should we say?

Comment: @msh210 You have to promise to star one of my chat posts so I can get the badge :)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12231.

Comment: Of course, if you _don't_ get the badge, we won't know whether someone who hasn't gotten it on the main site would have gotten it on meta having done what we're doing. (Since you have gotten it on main, I mean.)

Comment: @msh210 Also related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8914/166155

Comment: Unrelated: http://goo.gl/C8PUV

Comment: @msh210 Definitely unrelated: [www.wwwdotcom.com](http://www.wwwdotcom.com/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2655/discussion-between-msh210-and-double-aa)

Answer (score 4):

The system is clearly not right. I am a dud user created for the sole purpose of testing this issue. I posted 10 messages in a meta started chat, got one stared, but got the talkative badge on the parent site. Some badges (like quorum) are not listed in the meta site because they are impossible here. So too with the chat badges. This is a **bug**.

Comment: meTAlkative, welcome to the site and thanks for your research! I expect I'll never see you here again :)

Answer (score 1):

Some badges cannot (or cannot easily) be awarded on meta. This is known and by design.

We always intentionally kept all badges listed, because it's a discovery mechanism. This goes back to the beta badge on graduated sites as well.

Comment: Why not Quorum or Convention?