# Reputation in Chat

Tags: support, chat, reputation

As usual, apologies if this has been asked before.

I'm just wondering if there is a different reputation calculator within Chat rooms, as my reputation is boosted there by about 200+ rep points relative to the  actual rep on my MY user screen.  Is this by design?

As an example, in Vedibarta Bam right now, I have 2801 reputation, but on my profile screen (and top right corner of regular Mi Yodeya, 2567).

Now I just noticed that it clearly added on my BH rep points, but not from any of my others (e.g. Mathematics Educators).  Why?

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/881/759

Comment: Why only some SE sites?

Comment: @doubleaa thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chat system actually uses three different servers -- one for Stack Overflow, one for SE Meta, and one for everything else.  On each server, reputation from all sites on the server contributes to your chat rep.  Chat counts only sites on which you've earned at least 200 reputation.

Your reputation for chat on Mi Yodeya (or most other sites) is therefore the sum of your reputation on all sites on which you've earned at least 200 rep, which for you is Mi Yodeya and BH.  If you had 200 rep on SO it wouldn't count.  If you enter a chat room on SO your Mi Yodeya (etc) rep won't count.  (I'm not sure which chat server hosts the other-language SO sites like SO in Spanish.)

Comment: The 200 rep cutoff would answer this, thanks!

Comment: It's 200, same as what it takes to be counted on the combined network flair.

Comment: @Scimonster thanks for confirming; I've edited.  I don't think that restriction used to be there, but without it it's really easy to abuse chat so it makes sense to have it.

Comment: I've been around for a few years, and it's been there as long as I can remember.